# How to create voice command inside immersion app - gdk

Tags: android, google-glass, gdk

I want to design a voice command to control(like a gesture) inside an app.
for example, instead of, swipe-right to go next card, using voice command "next".

Currently, I develop immersion card app, using gesture to control a cards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to using voice commands for navigating instead of using swipe gesture?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818039/is-it-possible-to-using-voice-commands-for-navigating-instead-of-using-swipe-ges)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the solution for this question,

If you want to know please go to this [Is it possible to using voice commands for navigating instead of using swipe gesture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818039/is-it-possible-to-using-voice-commands-for-navigating-instead-of-using-swipe-ges/27914886#27914886)

Hope this help !