# Is it possible to using voice commands for navigating instead of using swipe gesture?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

**Hi, there**

Currently, I'm develop an immersion app to provide a text on screen and user can swipe_right to go another one.

Actually, It adapt from sample immersion pattern called [charades](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/patterns/immersion)(google development site).

My objective is, I want to using voice commands, instead of SWIPE gesture.

for example;

1. User open the immersion demo, the screen will show first TEXT.
2. User want to go next TEXT by *using voice "GO NEXT"*.
3. The screen will show another Text.

Considering this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652321/how-to-navigate-a-google-glass-gdk-immersion-application-using-voice-command-onl?rq=1)!

***Is there any way to do this?
or any suggestion?***

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html Use this as a service to run in background..Invoke SpeechRecognizer when ViewPager is in foreground. Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for your advice, btw, could you give an example for this one?  @VnyKumar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940657/android-speech-recognition-as-a-service-on-android-4-1-4-2/14950616#14950616 this should be a good starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, **It is my solution.** Hope this might helped someone who looking for.

I used `Contextual voice commands` to provide 'Next', 'Save' and 'Exit' commands for an user. you can go to [this document](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#contextual_voice_commands) from google dev site to see the ideas of doing this.

I have my layout *activity* to show some TEXT, so I put this code structure. in my layout activity

```
    //contextual voice command
import com.google.android.glass.view.WindowUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


@Override
public boolean onCreatePanelMenu(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    // Pass through to super to setup touch menu.
    return super.onCreatePanelMenu(featureId, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    if (featureId == WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.save_menu_item:
                Log.d("Contextual", "go save checks");  
                break;
            case R.id.next_menu_item:
                Log.d("Contextual", "go next checks");                    
                break;
            case R.id.exit_menu_item:
                Log.d("Contextual", "go exit checks");                    
                break;
            default:
                return true;
        }

        return true;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

*Don't forget* to declare this line `getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);` to your onCreate(); before your `setContentView()`.

Next thing, I created 'menu folder' and `main.xml` inside its to provide my item selection. Like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/next_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/next">

</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/save_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/save_this">
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/exit_menu_item"
    android:title="@string/exit">
</item>
```

and my `strings.xml` file.

```
<resources>
   <string name="next">next</string>
   <string name="save_this">save</string>
   <string name="exit">exit</string>
</resources>
```

put this line 
`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />`

to your `AndroidMenifest.xml`.

**and it works fine for me !**